# "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" error on every page except homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I've been using Google PageSpeed insights to try and improve my site's performance, and so far it's proven extremely successful - but only on the homepage for some reason.

The homepage is given a score of 87/100 with 8 passed rules, one of them being "You have no render-blocking resources."

**The problem**

When I check any of the other pages it states "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content". Now, both the homepage and the other pages include the same head.php & footer.php, no page loads extra .js or .css files not already loaded on the homepage.

**Head**

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Boxed version of "Our Clients"" />
<meta name="author" content="Luke" />
<title>Boxed - Our Clients &ndash; DDME</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?modified=01-01-1970-00-00-00" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://templates.ddme.co.uk/our-clients/boxed/" />
    <style>
 .body-wrapper{visibility:hidden}
 .preloader{position:absolute;top:50%;left:46.5%;background:rgba(51,51,51,0.8);padding:15px;text-align:center;transform: translateY(-50%);border-radius:4px;z-index:999}
 .preloader > img{width:40px;height:40px}
 </style>
</head>
```

**Footer**

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/defecto/js/loadCSS.min.js"></script>
<script>
loadCSS("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css");
loadCSS("/themes/defecto/css/foundations.min.css?modified=28-04-2015-15-28-52");
loadCSS("/themes/defecto/css/style.css?modified=29-04-2015-10-42-15");
loadCSS("/themes/defecto/js/lightbox/css/lightbox.css");
loadCSS("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
</script>
<script src="//use.typekit.net/fyc5nlq.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="/themes/defecto/js/scrollfix.min.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/defecto/js/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/defecto/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So... is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: The reason is that your homepage is making use of the included javascript and stylesheet in full (or almost) where as your other pages don't need everything from within the included assets and therefore it's called block rendering above the fold. You can check it out by creating a separate css and javascript file for your other pages containing only the used css and javascript above the fold.